# Serializing Spark.ml Pipeline model and write out to pickle file

Tags: pyspark, model, pipeline

I'm trying to serialize a spark.ml pipeline model so that I can write it out to a pickle file. I've tried multiple options, including the MLeap library to serialize, model.save('Path') and any attempts to pickle result in a thread._RLock error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I've also tried converting the model representation to JSON

```
import json
def convert_to_dict(mdl):
    if hasattr(mdl, 'stages'):
        return {'stages': [convert_to_dict(s) for s in mdl.stages]}
    else:
        return {'params': mdl.extractParamMap}
```

and then doing a JSON.dump

```
serializeModel = convert_to_dict(model)
with open(r'\SerialModel\AngModel.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(serializeModel, file)
```

Which results in error

```
TypeError: Object is not JSON serializable
```

I then tried the spark serializer

```
Serialmodel = sc.serializer.serializer.dumps(model)
```

Which results in error

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

The standard pickle also results in the above '_thread.RLock' error

```
with open('myModel.pkl','wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file)
```

Cloud pickle also reults in the same error

```
with open('myModel.pkl', 'wb') as out:
    cloudpickle.dumps(model,protocol=5)
```

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```